# How to add a bookmarklet in the context menu?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to add a bookmarklet in the context menu.

This is my bookmarklet:

> javascript:(function(){var a=window.open('http://localhost/test/mm.php?title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title),'test','left='+((window.screenX||window.screenLeft)+50)+',top='+((window.screenY||window.screenTop)+50)+',height=300px,width=700px,resizable=1,alwaysRaised=1,location=1,links=0,scrollbars=0,toolbar=0');window.setTimeout(function(){a.focus()},300)})();

This is my code:

```
function getClickHandler() {
  return function(info, tab) {

  };
};

chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title" : "Hello",
  "type" : "normal",
  "onclick" : getClickHandler()
});
```

But now, I don't know where insert the bookmarklet.

**@wong2:**

This is my new getClickHandler but it doesn't work:

```
function getClickHandler() {
  return function(info, tab) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
          code: "(function(){var a=window.open('http://localhost/test/mm.php?title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title),'test','left='+((window.screenX||window.screenLeft)+50)+',top='+((window.screenY||window.screenTop)+50)+',height=300px,width=700px,resizable=1,alwaysRaised=1,location=1,links=0,scrollbars=0,toolbar=0');window.setTimeout(function(){a.focus()},300)})();"
      });
  };
};
```

Manifest.json:

```
{
  "name" : "testtt",
  "version" : "1.0.1",
  "description" : "test button",
  "background" : { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
  "permissions" : [
    "contextMenus",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
   ],
  "minimum_chrome_version" : "6.0.0.0",
  "icons" : {
    "16" : "imageinfo-16.png",
    "48" : "imageinfo-48.png",
    "128" : "imageinfo-128.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [chrome.tabs.executeScript](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) to insert your code to the page:

```
function getClickHandler() {
  return function(info, tab) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
          code: YOUR_CODE_IN_STRING_HERE
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: because the real bookmarklet is very complex and doesn't work in this way :(

Comment: @xRobot Have you declared permissions for both `contextMenus` and `tabs`?

Comment: Can you post your manifest.json ? I have posted now in the question above and how you can see, I have declared permission for both contextmenus and tabs

Comment: uhmm, are you sure that the getClickHandler is the same ?

Comment: @xRobot yes. You can open the chrome extension manage page, and click `Inspect views: background.html` of your extension to see if there's errors there

Comment: @xRobot I'm also under ubuntu. = =